# DeserializeObject with dynamic name [Json.net]

Tags: c#, json

Dearl all
I have a json string with format line

```
  "rain":{"3h":0.46}
```

In this case , 'rain' have '3h' object but with this name is dynamic so i can't deserialize object it with JsonConvert , so what are define in class with this name ?

Json2Csharp give me this code

```
    public class Rain
{
    public double __invalid_name__3h { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in javascript (and thus JSON) are simply dictionaries. Since you don't know the property name (and more importantly, since it begins with a number which is forbidden in C#), you can simply use a dictionary:

```
public class MyThing 
{
    public Dictionary<string, double> rain { get; set; }
}
```

However, your JSON is incomplete. It should be:

```
{"rain":{"3h":0.46}}
```

Fully working:

```
void Main()
{
    var json =  @"{""rain"":{""3h"":0.46}}";
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyThing>(json);
}

public class MyThing
{
    public Dictionary<string, double> rain { get; set; }
}
```